# How to access the bing search api and store the results into marklogic server?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, bing-api

I want to store the xml file/files returned on accessing the search URL into ML 8 server.
This is what I'm trying:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $xml := xdmp:http-get("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27Vin%20Diesel%27",
     <options xmlns="xdmp:http">
       <authentication>
         <password>myPassword</password>
       </authentication>
     </options>)
     return xdmp:document-insert("/result",$xml[1],xdmp:default-permissions(),"news");
```

However this returns me a error as follows:

> [1.0-ml] SVC-SOCHN: xdmp:http-get("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27Vi...", myPassword...) -- Socket hostname error: gethostbyname api.datamarket.azure.com: Host not found
>
> Stack Trace
>   At line 8 column 43:
>
> In xdmp:eval("xquery version "1.0-ml";
> let $xml:= xdmp:http-get(...", (), 3904735945144540670270578192404822...)
>
> $xml := xdmp:http-get("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News?Query=%27Vi...", myPassword...)
>
> )
>   return xdmp:document-insert("/result",**$xml[1]**,xdmp:default-permissions(),"news");

There are no issues with the URL. I promise it is correct.

I want to basically store all the results from the bing search api into marklogic. What's wrong? If this is not the right approach is there another approach that I can try?

Thanks. Appreciate any help that I can get here.

Comment: Can you make request from the server via `curl` or `wget`? Can you ping `api.datamarket.azure.com`?

Answer (score 0):

When I run the same xdmp:http-get command, I get a "certificate verify failed" error, which makes sense for not having a correct password. Looks like the problem is reaching the host. There could be a firewall on the host running MarkLogic that is preventing the outbound traffic, or it might not be configured with a DNS.